# ¿Cambiar la forma de ordenar automaticamente el codigo en netbeans 8.2?

Tags: java, netbeans

En netbeans en el código de un proyecto, cuando se presiona: <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
Reordena el código automaticamente, pero lo reordena de esta forma:

```
try{
     if(1>2){

     } else { 

     }
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

Mi duda viene, en que si no hay alguna forma en las configuraciones o hacer algún comando para que lo ordene de esta forma, agregando el salto de línea:

```
try
{
    if(1>2)
    {

    } 
    else 
    { 

    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

Comment: Me imagino eres desarrollador C# y ahora usas Java, es así Alexander? =)

Comment: Pues si comencé con C#, y me he acostumbrado a tener las llaves ordenadas así, lo veo mas ordenado y fácil de leer la verdad .

Comment: Que bien, lo imaginaba Alexander, te comento por experiencia en mi caso, cuando escribo un código de miles de lineas, en ocasiones ya no es cool, porque.esos saltos de linea hacen expandir tu código bastante. Pero si te gusta como lo realiza en VS es válido ☺ .

Comment: Ciertamente últimamente tengo un proyecto grande y tengo formularios con mas de 2000 lineas, y esos saltos son bastantes, pero para organizarme me funciona bien :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto lo puedes configurar  en Mac desde `Netbeans` > `Preferences` > `Editor` > `Formatting` 
, en Windows: `Window` > `Options` > `Editor` > `Formatting`

ve a `Language:` `Java` y `Category:` `Braces`

configura `Method declaration` y `Other:`  como `New Line` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma, al aplicar el formato se aplicara como lo deseas en tu pregunta.